# Ruby iterating over hash of hash

Tags: ruby

I have the following array and am struggling to format it for my needs.

```
consolidated = [
  {:name=>"Bob",   :details=>{"work"=>"Carpenter", "age"=>"26", "Experience"=>"6"} },
  {:name=>"Colin", :details=>{"work"=>"painting",  "age"=>"20", "Experience"=>"4"} }
]
```

I am trying to format it as below:

```
Bob    work         Carpenter
       age          26
       Experience   6

Colin  work         painting
       age          20
       Experience   4
```

I tried the following:

```
require 'csv'
CSV.open("output.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  csv << ["name", "nature", "details"]
  consolidated.each do |val|
    csv << [val[:name], val[:details]]
  end
end
  #=> [{:name=>"Bob",   :details=>{"work"=>"Carpenter", "age"=>"26", "Experience"=>"6"}},
  #    {:name=>"Colin", :details=>{"work"=>"painting", "age"=>"20", "Experience"=>"4"}}]
```

but it prints the following

```
name      nature                                                  details

Bob      "work"=>"Carpenter", "age"=>"26", "Experience"=>"6"

Colin    "work"=>"painting", "age"=>"20", "Experience"=>"4"
```

I'm not exactly sure how to iterate hash of hash from the 1st loop only to get the expected format.

Thanks.

Comment: Your iterating is fine, there's really no other way. It's just your formatting/printing that needs improvement.

Comment: Also please don't call that a CSV file. It isn't. Even if you used tab separators (which you don't), it would still yield unexpected data when parsing (nil/empty rows).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev : I'm unable to construct the format of my need and with my limited knowledge is not helping my cause too... Any help would be really helpful, like an example.. and I want  to export to an excel

Comment: "and I want to export to excel" - you can use gem `axlsx` to write an .xlsx file directly. Much more reliable results.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion suggested

Comment: I made some corrections with an edit.  Your "data structure" was not a valid Ruby object. When giving an example ensure that all inputs are valid Ruby objects and assign a variable to each (here `consolidated`). The latter is to allow readers (and even the asker,  as you have done) to refer to such variables in answers and comments. You had the line `csv << [[val[:name], val[:details]]`, which has unbalanced brackets. I removed the first left bracket. (cont.).

Comment: ..There are still problems that you need to fix with an edit. Where you say, "I am trying to format it as below :", what is "it"? Do you mean you want to print that to the terminal? Secondly, where you say, "but it prints as:", what is "it" and what do you mean by "prints as"? I don't see any `puts` statements.

Comment: In view of your exchange with @Sergio above, and the fact that you gave him the greenie, I think your question should be the following. "Within Excel I wish to import a CSV file named `"output.csv"` that contains the information in the following array (`consolidate`) so that I may print (from Excel) the table shown below the array. How do I construct the needed CSV file from the array `consolidated`?" Then after the table give the code you tried and explain why it didn't work. If my understanding is correct, feel free to use any of these words in your edit.

Comment: I should add that the edit needs to be done even though you've selected an answer. Many members may read your question in future and you owe it to them to be clear about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's something to get you started:

```
require 'csv'
data = [
  {:name => "Bob", :details=>{"work"=>"Carpenter", "age"=>"26", "Experience"=>"6"}},
  {:name => "Colin", :details=>{"work"=>"painting", "age"=>"20", "Experience"=>"4"}}
]

str = CSV.generate do |csv|
  data.each do |datum|
    datum[:details].each do |detail_key, detail_value|
      csv << [datum[:name], detail_key, detail_value]
    end
  end
end

puts str
# >> Bob,work,Carpenter
# >> Bob,age,26
# >> Bob,Experience,6
# >> Colin,work,painting
# >> Colin,age,20
# >> Colin,Experience,4
```

Simply iterate all details and emit a new row for each key-value pair there, adding a name of a person.

This will get you *almost* what you need. Missing only blank rows between sections and person's name is duplicated on each line. It'll be your homework to find out how to add those improvements.

Comment: Thank you very much and guiding a new guy to the Ruby world

Comment: What if I wanted to write Bob and colins once

Comment: @dev: then you'd need to sometimes pass `nil` instead of `datum[:name]`. Maybe raise and track a flag of some sort?

Comment: ...and to inform any that don't realize that statement is `require`d. Wouldn't it be better to write a header row, `"name, work, age, experience"`, then `"Bob, carpenter, 26, 6"`, followed by `"Colin, painter, 28, 4"`? Note I could not bring myself to capitalise "experience" when "work" and "age" are not capitalized, or capitalise "carpenter" in view or "painting", or have Bob a carpenter and Colin a painting.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: I agree, this format is... curious. Not what I would choose. But I don't know their requirements. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: See my penultimate comment on the question. That's my take.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: yep, yours sounds closer to reality.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about CSV generation (so, assuming it works as you have written), you can iterate on your object this way:

```
consolidated = [{:name => "Bob", :details=>{"work"=>"Carpenter", "age"=>"26", "Experience"=>"6"}}, {:name => "Colin", :details=> {"work"=>"painting", "age"=>"20", "Experience"=>"4"}}]


CSV.open("output.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  csv << ["name", "nature", "details"]

  consolidated.each do |val|
    details = val[:details]
    nature_1 = details.keys.first
    detail_1 = details.delete(nature_1)
    csv << [val[:name], nature_1, detail_1]

    details.each do |k, v|
      csv << [nil, k, v]
    end
  end
end
```

**Note:** This will corrupt your original data array `consolidated`. So, if you want to preserve it, `dup` it first. Or modify the logic to not delete the first key-value from `val[:details]`.

Comment: There's no need for breaking/corrupting the data structure you were simply asked to print. :)

Comment: Yeah, my bad. i will mention it in the answer.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh Appreciate your inputs here !!

Comment: Duping `consolidated` wouldn't help. One needs a deep dup/clone here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate the embedded hash by `each_pair` iterator.
Something like this:

```
data = {:name => "Bob", :details=>{"work"=>"Carpenter", "age"=>"26", "Experience"=>"6"}}

CSV.open("output.csv", "wb") do |csv|

  csv << ["name", "nature", "details"]

  data.each do |val|

    csv << [ val[:name], val[:details]['work'] ]

    data[:details].each_pair do |key, value]

      # here we have to drop the first pair because i've used it earlier 
      next if key == 'work'

      csv << [ "", key, value ]

    end

  end

end
```

Comment: This snippet is full of syntax errors. And there's at least one logical error there too.

Comment: In one line I almost stepped on the do do. The double spacing is a bit odd.